# Non-blocking write into a in-order queue

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have a buffer created with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` flags. I have used this in one kernel and then downloaded (`queue.enqueueReadBuffer(...)`) the data back to the host memory set when the buffer was created. I have modified these data on CPU and now I'd like to use them in another kernel.
When I have uploaded (`queue.enqueueWriteBuffer`) the data manually using non-blocking write and then enqueued kernel with this buffer as argument, it returned the `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` error. Blocking write was just fine.

Why did this happen? I thought that the blocking/non-blocking version only controls if I can work with the memory on CPU after the `enqueueWriteBuffer` call returns, with in-order queue there should be no difference for the kernel.
Second question is whether I have to upload it manually at all - does the `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` mean that the data has to be uploaded from host to device in for every time some kernel uses the buffer as argument? As I have to download the data manually when I require them, has the above mentioned flag any pros?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure of the specific problem for your `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` error.  This error seems to be raised as kind of a catch-all for problems in the system, so the actual error you're getting might be caused by something else in your program (maybe the kernel).

In regards to using the `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, you still still have to manually upload the data.  The OpenCL specification states:

> This flag is valid only if host_ptr is not NULL. If specified, it
>   indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to use
>   memory referenced by host_ptr as the storage bits for the memory
>   object. OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer
>   contents pointed to by host_ptr in device memory. This cached copy can
>   be used when kernels are executed on a device.

For some devices the data will be cached on the device memory.  In order to sync your data you would have to use some `clEnqueueReadBuffer` / `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` or `clEnqueueMapBuffer` / `clEnqueueUnmapBuffer`.  For discrete CPU+GPU combinations (i.e. seperate GPU card), I'm not sure what benefit there would be to doing `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, since the data will be cached anyway.

Upon reading the specification, there might be some performance benefit for using `clEnqueueMapBuffer` / `clEnqueueUnmapBuffer` instead of `clEnqueueReadBuffer` / `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, but I haven't tested this for any real devices.

Best of luck!